# How to correctly setup cmake for glfw on clion on MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, clion, glfw

I've recently bought a Macbook and I want to start writing some OpenGL code for a project.

SPECIFICATIONS

- MacOS
- Macbook pro 16inch 2019
- Clion
- glfw3 (precompiled binaries 64 bit)

The CMake doesn't complain, but as soon as I start compiling I get the following error

```
    /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/arnesix/Documents/dev/c++/graphics/cmake-build-debug --target graphics -- -j 12
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable graphics
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CFArrayAppendValue", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFArrayCreateMutable", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFArrayGetCount", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
      _closeJoystick in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformPollJoystick in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFArrayGetValueAtIndex", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
      _closeJoystick in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformPollJoystick in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFArraySortValues", referenced from:
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
```

The binaries I have downloaded from https://www.glfw.org/download.html only contain the 64 bit binaries.

I am using the following cmake code and folder structure
[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glfw3.h>

int main() {
    std::cout << glfwInit() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and lastly, my Cmake preferences

[image]

I would love to know why this keeps happening and how I should resolve this issue.

Comment: Please, add to the question post the code and the error message in **textual form**, not as image. This is a requirement of Stack Overflow. See also [ask].

Comment: Unrelated: you should use the `target_*` variants of seting include and linker directories, as they only apply to that target instead of everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read [the documentation](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html#build_link_osx)? You're missing three frameworks if you compile like that:

```
target_link_libraries(graphics glfw3 -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit)
```

Better to just use [the find_package approach](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html#build_link_cmake_package)

Comment: I have never used CMake in my life. I came from windows where visual studio handled everything.

Appearantly I messed up the order of the CMake file, the problem seems to be resolved right now.

Comment: @TheAlphaKarp, can you please elaborate on how you've resolved it. I have exact the same problem as in your question. Thanks!

Comment: I am so sorry, but I don't have that project anymore, All I remember was that the order of find_package was important in the project.

Using XCode to solve this is easier than clion.
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Installation/Mac

Comment: @seelts Here is some documentation that hopefully helps you further

https://www.programmersought.com/article/85305491112/

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.
I'm using *local* (not system-wide) `glfw` with `glad`.
Here is my cmake file I've ended up with which worked for me.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(project_name)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
if (APPLE)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-framework Cocoa -framework IOKit")
    # -framework OpenGL -framework CoreVideo
    add_compile_definitions(GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION)
endif ()

include_directories(<your include dir here>)
add_executable(project_name <your source files here>)

target_link_libraries(project_name <path to libglfw3.a>)
```

The line which actually helped me was `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-framework Cocoa -framework IOKit")`

`GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION` part seems to have no impact, so probably can be ignored.